# Searching a large DOM for an element at the end

Tags: selenium, dom, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium on a page with a large DOM (1000 lines, ~10,000 nodes). I am trying to determine if an element exists, which is located at almost the very end of the DOM.

The structure is something like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <section></section>
        <script></script>
        <span>
            // several more wrappers around the UL
            <ul id="itemsList"></ul>
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where the `section` node contains 99% of the lines.

I know that the UL will always be in the same place.

The XPath I am using is the following:

```
//body/span//ul
```

If the UL exists, the search takes <500ms. But if the UL does not exist, the search will take 2-5 seconds. I don't understand this as I would expect the traversal to happen in the same way and take the same amount of time.

As I am using selenium, I have also tried using `By.Id`, but this gives the same result.

Comment: Do you have an implicit timeout in your code?

Comment: Additionally to the comment above I would recommend to try using getElementsByXpath(or List<WebElement>) and check size of that list.

Comment: Think of searching your hard drive for a file starting at root (C:\).  Compare that to starting at C:\Users\you\Documents\projects\foobar\meetingMinutes\2015\January\

The more of the DOM structure that you specify in your XPath the smaller the number of paths that selenium has to search and the faster that search will complete.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 But I am specifying `body/span`. Since there is only a single `span` node in `body` this should not have traverse the entire DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Might be because of Explicit wait commands in your code. If selenium can find element within **Implicit wait** it moves on to next step But if it could not find the element in implicit wait time it checks for **Explicit wait** and if you have given explicit wait for this element Selenium will wait until the explicit wait time before throwing exception.